# NHibernate write value = NULL when ID < 0

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, null

We would like to implement a simple rule in which NHibernate would assign (persist) NULL to the database when the ID for the entity is equal to -1. For example, we have an "in system" account which should be persisted to the database as NULL.

If we try to persist the ID of -1 to the database we get a Foreign key exception because the ID does not exist in the foreign table.

We are using NHibernate with FluentNhibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't a proper mapping of your entity. If it were correct, you should made any trick: you should not see an ID, but a reference to another entity, and in this case you will persist the reference with a null value. Even in the wrong case you want map the entity with a reference expressed as an ID ( that is almost always wrong ) if this id is nullable, map it as a nullable so you have int? and you can fit null to mean null, instead of the -1 trick.

**See Comments**

If a custom entity is internally used as a null value, a session interceptor could help: working on the OnSave and treat the special case by replacing the dummy entity with null.
[Here you can find the documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-11-interceptors-and/1nr4enxv3dpeq/14) about NH interceptors.
At the 11.2 chaper od the same doc there is the portion related to events, equivalents for this kind of problem.

Comment: thank you Felice. I should clarify. We are persisting a reference to the object, not the ID itself. We create an object with ID = -1 internal in the application. If this entity is assigned to a property, the property value persisted to the database should be NULL

Comment: thank you Felice. I read that interceptors have been replaced by events in the latest version of NHibernate. What event listeners would I need to create for OnLoad and OnSave?